# add system dependecies installed from source to rosdep check

Tags: rosdep

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,

I would like to know how to add a already installed package from source to the rosdep check.

My problem is in specific that I use a ARM Platform and could not install yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev from binaries (is needed from the uvc_camera package and many more). So I installed it from source without any problems.
When I'm now using following commad:

```
$rosmake --rosdep-install uvc_camera
```

it still complains about the missing yaml dependency but When I'm using:

```
$rosmake --no-rosdep uvc_camera
```

It compiles and works. Now I want to now how I can define that yaml is already installed on the machine.

I would be glad to get a hint here...
Cheers

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38315/add-system-dependecies-installed-from-source-to-rosdep-check/) by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 447 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-09**:
Which ROS distribution are you using?

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-07-09**:
I'm using ROS electric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Perhaps the (unaccepted) answer in [this](http://answers.ros.org/question/36029/build-ros-fuerte-from-source-agains-boost-1490/?answer=38191#post-id-38191) question can help you (the bit about equivs).

---

EDIT: example equivs file which you could use:

```
Section: devel
Priority: optional
Standards-Version: 3.6.2
Package: yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev-meta
Version: 0.2.6-4~lucid
Maintainer: dinamex <dinamex@fake.pack.age>
Provides: yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev
Architecture: all
Description: Meta package providing the 'yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev' ROS dependency
 Package provides the 'yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev' package, without installing the
 actual files.
```

---

EDIT2: yet another option would be to just build an ARM version of the `yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev` and install that. `makeinstall` or `dpkg-buildpackage` could help you with that. See also the answer from @joq.

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-07-09**:
Is there a different way? I just want to make clear that one package is installed. It can't be that complicated that I need to trick the system. Even this answer points out "This is somewhat of an 'advanced' technique though, as you can create some pretty interesting apt conflicts this way"

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-09**:
I just added that warning to indicate that you should know at least something about apt and its dependency system. Using equivs and injecting a single meta-package to satisfy a dependency shouldn't pose any problems, as long as you document what you did somewhere.

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-09**:
And it isn't really that complicated: the equivs file will probably be a few lines at maximum, after which you build it (using equivs) and install it (using dpkg). Another option could be to edit the dependencies of all packages that require the `yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev` file.

**Comment by [dinamex](https://answers.ros.org/users/1383/dinamex/) on 2012-07-09**:
Thank you. I will try that... but how come that my system doesn't recognize my installed version?

**Comment by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) on 2012-07-09**:
Most likely since the files exist on your disk, but the package manager doesn't know this. So when ROS checks for this dependency, it won't find it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try building `yaml-cpp0.2.6-dev` like the Ubuntu package. I *think* it is built from one of these git repositories:

- For electric: https://kforge.ros.org/rosrelease/yamlcppdebs
- For fuerte: https://github.com/wg-debs/yaml_cpp-release

I am not certain exactly how this is done, but it is probably worth a try.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1